# How to create user agent?

Tags: r, edgar

I'm trying out this function from the package edgarwebR

```
x <- paste0("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/",
            "933691/000119312517247698/0001193125-17-247698-index.htm")
try(filing_information(x))
```

But it returns me the following

```
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
Error in check_result(res) : 
  EDGAR request blocked from Undeclared Automated Tool.
Please visit https://www.sec.gov/developer for best practices.
See https://mwaldstein.github.io/edgarWebR/index.html#ethical-use--fair-access for your responsibilities
Consider also setting the environment variable 'EDGARWEBR_USER_AGENT
```

So I went to SEC and the information tells me to declare my user agent in the request headers. I'm new to this. How do I create a user agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the edgar package so I'm not sure this is helpful. But this is how I would do it using edgar package

```
library("edgar")    
useragent = "Your Name Contact@domain.com"
info <- getFilingInfo('933691', 2021, quarter = c(1,2,3,4), form.type = 'ALL', useragent)
```